# How to make an android apk file in android studio that runs in all mobiles for testing purpose only

Tags: android, android-studio

I'm new to android, When i'm installing android app via USB cable manually it's running but i want to share it and run in another mobile phones for testing purpose for that what i've to do?

Comment: According to the Android Dashboards, API Level 10 is still supported. Therefore, `runs in all mobiles` doesn't match with `i've also set the minimum android API 15`

Comment: What do you mean by all mobile phones? I guess you have tried to run it in one specific mobile phone, if its config doesn't match what you have set, you can not install it in it, if it does match so you are not telling the problem right

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to **Build** menu, then click on **Build APK**. A pop-up appears having title **Build APK** 
*APK(s) generated successfully. 
Show in Explorer*. Then click on Show in Explorer and your APK file is ready to share.

Comment: Thanks, @Rohit Singh

Answer (score 0):

What's the real issue..? Take the APK and simply sideload it in another phone. Or, connect the phone with your machine.

Firebase offers a limited test for any real and virtual devices on your choice. Use the free services everyday to test it on all available devices.